# How do I treat an array of 64 bytes as an array of 16 ints (and vice versa) in C without using a union?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types, type-conversion

So, in my program, I have a variable

```
uint32_t buffer[16];
```

However, there are some times where I need to treat this as

```
uint8_t char_buffer[64];
```

The most obvious solution is a union. However, out of intellectual curiosity, is there another way to tell the compiler that I want to treat the array as an array of some arbitrary type? Something along the lines of

```
((uint8_t *)buffer)[i]
```

?

Comment: You can cast it to force the array to be recognized as the other type.

Comment: What is the problem with casting?

Comment: Thanks guys, I thought I tried it earlier and it didn't work. Turns out I was wrong, it works fine. Picked up some good info anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The casting approach is perfect. It *will* make the compiler treat the array as an array of ints. In your particluar case, use

```
((uint32_t *)buffer)[index];
```

As @JerryCoffin points out, however, there's a probem with alignment. If you statically allocate the array statically as a `char []`, it won't necessarily be 4-byte aligned (which is needed for integers). If you surely want to avoid this problem, use `malloc()` as it guarantees an appropriate alginment.

Comment: There is a potential problem with alignment though. A buffer of `char` isn't necessarily aligned to allow access as a `uint32_t` (though if you allocated it with `malloc` or `calloc` that would be guaranteed).

Comment: Thanks for the info, guys. If I statically allocate it as an array of ints, I should be fine though, right?

Answer (score 3):

The ISO C99 standard says:

> When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

This says that if `uint8_t` is `typedef unsigned char` (and it must be if `uint8_t` exists in your system at all), then  your code must work: array reference is equivalent to a dereferenced pointer + int addition.

Note that this works only when casting *to* `char`.  Casting the other way or to anything else is only guaranteed to work in the sense that you can eventually cast back, and the final will be equal to the original value.  For example, you couldn't cast from an array of 32-bit longs to an array of 16-bit shorts and be sure of anything under the standard, though it's likely to work in practice with most CPU/compiler combinations.

Comment: +1. If it exists, `uint8_t` *is* `unsigned char`. This is because `char` has at least 8 bit, there can't be a type that is narrower than `char`, and both types must use all bits, padding bits are not allowed, here.